# Application of Ito's lemma

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance-mathematics, itos-lemma

Let $X_t$ be some stochastic process driven by wiener process ($W_t)$ so it can be expressed as:
$$dX_t=(...)dt+(...)dW_t$$

Let $f(t,x)$ be some $C^2$ function. Define the process $Z_s=f(t-s,X_s)$ for $0<s<t$ and **fixed**  $t$.

**How can I use Ito's lemma to express $dZ_s$?**

The reason for this question and my confusion is the $(t-s)$ part. Naturally $f(t,X_t)$ and $f(t-s,X_{t-s})$ would have been easy, but how does the standard Ito change when the process looks is $(t-s,X_{t-s})$?

Maybe one can show Ito is performed in general for $f(g(t),X_t)$ where in the above case: $g(t)=T-t$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider OP's general formula $f(g(t),X_t)$. In case of ambiguity, let us claim that

- $f=f(t,x)$ is defined with variables $t$ and $x$,
- $g=g(s)$ is defined with the variable $s$, and
- $h=h(u,x)=f(g(u),x)$ is defined with variables $u$ and $x$.

Then Ito's formula states that
$$
{\rm d}h(u,X_u)=\frac{\partial h}{\partial u}(u,X_u)\,{\rm d}u+\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}(u,X_u)\,{\rm d}X_u+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2h}{\partial x^2}(u,X_u)\,{\rm d}\left<X\right>_u.
$$

We just need to express $h$ by using $f$ and $g$. We have
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial h}{\partial u}(u,x)&=\frac{\partial}{\partial u}h(u,x)=\frac{\partial}{\partial u}f(g(u),x)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(g(u),x)\,\frac{{\rm d}g}{{\rm d}s}(u),\\
\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}(u,x)&=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}h(u,x)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(g(u),x)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(g(u),x),\\
\frac{\partial^2h}{\partial x^2}(u,x)&=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}h(u,x)=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}f(g(u),x)=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}(g(u),x).
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$
{\rm d}f(g(u),X_u)={\rm d}h(u,X_u)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(g(u),X_u)\frac{{\rm d}g}{{\rm d}s}(u)\,{\rm d}u+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(g(u),X_u)\,{\rm d}X_u+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}(g(u),X_u)\,{\rm d}\left<X\right>_u.
$$

---

Back to OP's original question, let us apply the above result to $f(T-u,X_u)$ (I would like to thank @Ezy for kind advices). In this case, let us take
$$
g(s)=T-s.
$$
Then we have
$$
\frac{{\rm d}g}{{\rm d}s}(u)=-1.
$$
Substitute these two expressions into the above result, and it follows that
$$
{\rm d}f(T-u,X_u)=-\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(T-u,X_u)\,{\rm d}u+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(T-u,X_u)\,{\rm d}X_u+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}(T-u,X_u)\,{\rm d}\left<X\right>_u.
$$

Comment: Maybe you can complete the derivation

Comment: @Ezy: Thanks you for your reminder. I edited my answer, credited to you.

Comment: thanks. I edited my answer to point to yours and upvoted yours ;)

Comment: @Ezy: Wow it is so beyond the generous of you! Thank you :-)

Answer (score 3):

$t$ is fixed to simply apply Ito Lemma to $h(s,X_s)$ with the function $h: (s,x)\rightarrow f(t-s,x)$ and you get your answer. There's nothing special about it, I think you are a bit confused by the change of variable $s\rightarrow(t-s)$.

@hypernova has laid out the complete steps below for you.

Comment: $dZ_t=\frac{\partial f }{\partial t}(t-s,X_t)+\frac{\partial f }{\partial x}(t-s,X_t) dX_t
+\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial^2 x}(t-s,X_t)  (dX_t)^2.$

So this is how $dZ$ wil like like?

Comment: no this is incorrect

Comment: How does it look then?

Comment: I told you in the answer exactly how to proceed. I believe if you know about the Ito lemma then you should be able to perform this calculation yourself correctly. Hint: it's *almost* correct!

Comment: For me this is far from clear by your answer.

Comment: Did you apply Ito to function h ?

Comment: No. I simply don't understand the purpose of $h$. I am not a mathematician and to be honest I don't quite understand phrasings.

Comment: @econmajorr you know enough math to know Ito which is pretty advanced maths already. I am giving you a hint to apply Ito lemma (which you know) to a new function i defined in my answer, $h$. If you are not willing to give it a try it is your decision! But if you do you will see its purpose.